# Joomla redirecting to same page on mobile screens

Tags: joomla, responsive-design, redirect

I am making a website responsive. The problem that I am facing right now is that whenever I click any item in the menu, I am redirected to the home page. The URL itself is redirected to the home page.

- I also found that this issue is happening only on phones. The iPad,
  desktop and laptop versions are working fine.
- The redirection is only happening on the home page. If I open any sub-page directly, this issue does not occur.
- The menu module for home page is different from the rest of the website. I checked many times to find any such configuration related to redirection but I did not find any.
- It is a multi-language site.

I am not sure why this redirection is happening. You may go through the website link and check the issue on your phone. I have checked on iPhone 4 and Samsung Galaxy S. And both are having this issue.

I will provide more information if required.

Link to website: goo[dot]gl/x86zHX

Comment: Provide the correct link!

Comment: It works fine for me on both an Android 2.3 phone and Nexus. Do you have any plugins or components that have any sort of user agent detection? I don't see how this issue could happen if the generated HTML is correct.

Comment: Works fine on Galaxy S Note II and Android 4.1.2. Tested in default browser, chrome and dolphin.

Answer (score 0):

Based, on that link (http://www.humandiscovery.com/) — it must be a plugin or similar, I pulled the HTML for the module using Safari's web inspector on the iPhone, which looks correct:

```
<div class="m-show">
    <div class="moduletablemain gradient">
        <!-- The class on the root UL tag was changed to match the Blueprint nav style -->
        <ul class="joomla-nav">
            <li id="current" class="selected item108"><a href="/en/">Human Discovery</a></li>
            <li class="item109"><a href="/en/philosophy.html">Philosophy</a></li>
            <li class="item110"><a href="/en/about.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="item111"><a href="/en/courses.html">Courses</a></li>
            <li class="item112"><a href="/en/foundation.html">Foundation</a></li>
            <li class="item113"><a href="/en/geneva.html">Geneva</a></li>
            <li class="item114"><a href="/en/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to replicate this issue on your phone? Yes, the html is correct. I suspect this is related to module mis-configuration or SEF Urls. But I am not sure how to solve it. Amazingly, all the other similar menu modules are working fine.